# Use apply() to iterate linear regression models through multiple dependent variables

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, apply

I'm computing the model outputs for a linear regression for a dependent variable with 45 different id values.  How can I use tidy (dplyr, apply, etc.) code to accomplish this?

I have a dataset with three variables `data` = `c(id`, `distance`, `actPct)` such that `id` == 1:45; -10 <= `distance` <= 10; 0 <= `actsPct` <= 1.

I need to run a regression, `model0n`, on each value of `id`, such that `model0n` has out put in a new tibble/df.  I have completed it for a single regression:

```
model01 <- data %>% 
filter(id == 1) %>%
filter(distance < 1) %>%
filter(distance > -4)
model01 <- lm(data = model01, actPct~distance)
```

Example Data

```
set.seed(42)
id <- as.tibble(sample(1:45,100,replace = T))
distance <- as.tibble(sample(-4:4,100,replace = T))
actPct <- as.tibble(runif(100, min=0, max=1))
data01 <- bind_cols(id=id, distance=distance, actPct=actPct)
attr(data01, "col.names") <- c("id", "distance", "actPct")
```

I expect a new tibble or dataframe that has `model01`:`model45` so I can put all of the regression outputs into a single table.

Comment: `apply` is generally slow from my experience.

Comment: @NelsonGon, thank you, I had not experience a slow `apply` function before.  Is there something else you prefer?  Everything I have read indicated `apply` was faster than a `for loop`, so I thought I would give it a shot.

Comment: Could you see if this question could help? Seems similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53968490/how-to-use-map-from-purrr-and-mutate-from-dplyr-to-produce-a-glm-summary-table/53968810#53968810  Maybe use other members of the `apply` family but not `apply`(personal opinion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group_by`, `nest` and `mutate` with `map` from the `tidyverse` to accomplish this:

```
data01 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(models = map(data, ~ lm(actPct ~ distance, data = .x)))

# A tibble: 41 x 3
#       id data             models  
#    <int> <list>           <list>  
#  1    42 <tibble [3 x 2]> <S3: lm>
#  2    43 <tibble [4 x 2]> <S3: lm>
#  3    13 <tibble [2 x 2]> <S3: lm>
#  4    38 <tibble [4 x 2]> <S3: lm>
#  5    29 <tibble [2 x 2]> <S3: lm>
#  6    24 <tibble [5 x 2]> <S3: lm>
#  7    34 <tibble [5 x 2]> <S3: lm>
#  8     7 <tibble [3 x 2]> <S3: lm>
#  9    30 <tibble [2 x 2]> <S3: lm>
# 10    32 <tibble [2 x 2]> <S3: lm>
# ... with 31 more rows
```

See also the chapter in R for R for Data Science about many models: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html

**Data**

```
set.seed(42)
id <- sample(1:45, 100, replace = T)
distance <- sample(-4:4, 100, replace = T)
actPct <- runif(100, min = 0, max = 1)
data01 <- tibble(id = id, distance = distance, actPct = actPct)
```